# nginx as a proxy for NodeJS+socket.io: everything is OK except for big messages

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket, socket.io

As explained on [nginx's website](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html) I've used these settings for my nginx to proxy websockets to a NodeJS server:

```
location /socket.io/ {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

Everything works fine and socket.emit() / socket.on() send messages to each other; until I send a rather big text message (26 kB of html).

- this big message is not received by NodeJS (so I guess that the issue is on nginx side)
- there are no error on nginx log
- once this big message has been send by the client, NodeJS will stop receiving socket.io's heartbeats from this client.

What am I doing wrong?
Is there a nginx setting that I am not aware of?

Comment: What version of nginx are you using?

Comment: I'm using nginx/1.4.0

Comment: I get this problem when using your config: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'onClose' of null `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "solution" found is to use [haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu) to split the tcp stream between nginx and NodeJS.

It is not optimal because it adds yet-another-program in our stack, but it does the job.

It seems to me that nginx websocket support is still far from being production-ready.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these with your configuration:

```
proxy_buffers 8 2m;
proxy_buffer_size 10m;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 10m;
```

Reason : proxy_buffer default size is 4K or 8K. So it could be dropping those connections after the big  message causes buffer overflow. Check the default settings [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule) so that it meets you requirements.

Comment: On the contrary, I would turn off proxy buffering with `proxy_buffering off`.  Comet did not work with nginx buffering and I suspect WebSockets would have exactly this same sort of problem.  You'd think nginx would disable buffering automatically or at least put it in the default configuration if it were required but I guess enough people get by with bigger buffers.  If you're going to go the buffering route you should also add something like `large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;`.  See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/aku/5466527) for an example configuration.