# Nginx as proxy for webSocket server was slow to send big data

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy, socket.io

I am using nginx(version:Window-1.4.4 stable) to proxy my webSocket server which is using NodeJS and Socket.io. I changed niginx configuration according to nginx's [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html) to make it work for webSocket.

It works well when transport small data, but it turns out to be slow down when transport bigger data.

```
  console.time('retrieve-small-data')
  socket.emit('retrieve-small-data', {}, function (data) {
    console.timeEnd('retrieve-small-data') // =>  52.960ms 
  })

  console.time('retieve-bigger-data');
  socket.emit('retieve-bigger-data', {}, function (data) {
    console.timeEnd('retieve-bigger-data'); // => 25016.105ms 
  })
```

Small data has 424 characters, and bigger data has 11254 characters.

If it directly connects the webSocket server without nginx proxying, this issue disappears. The time of requesting bigger data is 82.901ms.

How to solve this issue? Any idea is appreciated.

Poor English, feel free to correct.

Comment: Looks like a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543787/nginx-as-a-proxy-for-nodejssocket-io-everything-is-ok-except-for-big-messages?rq=1)